# Why aren't my dynamically-added form inputs posting?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a form where I need to dynamically add inputs whenever the user clicks a "more widgets" button. There's a hidden div inside the form, and I append the inputs to it with jQuery, like this:

```
$('div#newwidgetinputs').show().append(newInputs);
```

They show up, are properly named, etc, but when I post the form, their contents are not in the PHP `$_POST` array.

So I tried just appending them to the form itself:

```
$('form#someform').append(newInputs);
```

They can't be seen on the page, but I give them default values, and this time they **do** appear in '$_POST'.

This makes me think that `div#newwidgetinputs` isn't considered part of the form, but I don't see why; it's between the opening and closing `<form>` tags.

Why wouldn't those inputs post?

Comment: If you show the elements after you add them does the data post?

Comment: Have you tested this in different browsers?

Have you tried debugging with Firebug or similar?

Comment: When you appending the widgets in the form directly, why aren't these shown? Could you post some html code?

Comment: @Pete - just using Firefox on Fedora. I'm a new developer here and don't have another browser installed. Have inspected with Firebug, but haven't really figured anything out.

Comment: @kgiannakakis - not sure. The form is inside a table. If I add a border to the table, I see it, but if I add one to the form, I don't. Not sure if that's normal - never tried it before. I can't easily post the HTML because there's a lot of proprietary PHP intermingled - sorry.

Comment: Is it possible that there's more than one `<div>` with that same "id" value?

Comment: Also, you'd probably have an answer by now if you'd posted at least some of your HTML.

Comment: @Pointy - nope, just the one.

Comment: Sorry, can't help without the source.  Though 'PHP intermingled' and 'form is inside a table' doesn't bode well either.

Comment: Yes, please add your HTML example here. Maybe someone else can test it then. Btw, years ago there was a Netscape bug that prevented css-hidden form fields from submitting. Doubt this affects Firefox. But anyway try another browser, or instead of display:none; try visibility:hidden; for your div#newwidgetinputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the HTML is not well-formed the browser might consider the dynamic inputs to be outside the form; for example:

```
<div id="div_1">
<form>
  <div id="div2">
  ... some HTML here
  </div></div>
  ... other HTML here
</form>
```

The 'other HTML' can be considered outside the form by the browser, since the second `</div>` closes the '#div_1' div, that is the container of the form, hence after the second `</div>` the browser consider the form to be closed.

Comment: I suspect that this is the problem. If only the question included some of the HTML!

Comment: OK, so it WAS the HTML structure - I had nested a table inside the form. When I just reversed the nesting so that the form was inside the table, it worked. I'm not sure why, since my other inputs were all working fine. Weird. But basically the HTML was the issue. Sorry to all those who asked to see source.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just fill in all the elements and just leave them hidden?  have another hidden field that gets set to 1 if the user clicks on add more widgets.